# Why doesn't pp-adaptive accept my refund amount?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

I am trying to implement partial PayPal refunds with pp-adaptive, but it refunds the full amount, rather than my specified amount.

My code:

```
    receiver_list = {receiver: [{ email: @transaction.email, amount: @amount}]}
    attributes = {currency_code: "USD", pay_key: @transaction.paypal_token,
                  receiver_list: receiver_list}
    response = client.execute(:Refund, attributes )
```

It has occurred to me that the problem may arise from passing in the wrong email, but I think it actually lies elsewhere. I will explain the issue with emails:

The [API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Refund_API_Operation/) indicates that

> The terms sender and receiver refer to sender and receivers of the original payment using the Pay API operation.

so it follows that the email field in the receiver should be that of the paypal account that *received* money in the original transaction. On the other hand, when describing the amount field of the receiver field, the API says:

> **amount** (Required) **xs:decimal**  Amount to be credited to the receiver's account.

Because it says this amount will be credited *to* the receiver, it seems as though the writer of the API has stopped using the convention they specified at the beginning, because by that nomenclature, the *sender* should be the one having a credit to their account in a refund.

Due to this ambiguity, I tried both passing in the receiver's and passing in the sender's emails. In both cases, I was not able to achieve a partial refund.

Like I said, I think the issue is something else, so please consider the entire code.

Thank you in advance for your replies.

Comment: Are you sure it's possible to refund just part of the payment? You don't mention specific docs anywhere is your question.

Comment: The API claims that it is. I linked it in my question (the word API is the link text), but here it is again: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Refund_API_Operation/

Comment: Sorr, I missed that. Will dig in tomorrow, since it's midnight here.

Comment: No problem. I've solved my issue though, Michal Szyndel. Thank you for the consideration anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer to my question. I wasn't making the request correctly. The following code and request (with the email replaced with the correct one) achieves a partial refund.

```
    receiver = {amount: @amount, email: “someone@somewhere.com"}
      receiver_list = [receiver: receiver]
      response = client.execute(:Refund, { currency_code: "USD", pay_key: @transaction.paypal_token, receiver_list: receiver_list} )
```

Taking stock of the differences, the receiver list should be an array, and the receiver should not be.